# What does the rawintden measurement in ImageJ mean?

Tags: pixel, imagej

I am having trouble understanding the rawintden measurement in imageJ. It outputs numbers as large as 300,000, but pixel intensity is only measured on a scale of 0-255. Why is this scale so much larger and what does the calculation represent?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The value raw integrated density (RawIntDen) is the sum of all pixel values in the ROI (region of interest). Dividing this value by the number of pixels in the ROI gives the Mean. Since it is the sum of several pixels, its value is usually larger than the bit-depth of the image.

There is another measurement called IntDen which is the Area multiplied by the Mean. In an uncalibrated image, RawIntDen and IntDen are equal.

Comment: Thank you! You are an ImageJ wizard! and thank you for the rapid response!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.